# Check boolean/LogicalVector in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I write this Rcpp function:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void check(Nullable<LogicalVector> group_center = R_NilValue) {
  if (group_center.isNotNull()) {
    if (group_center) {
      Rprintf("true.\n");
    } else {
      Rprintf("false.\n");
    }
  } else{Rprintf("null.\n");}
}
```

The goal of this function is that: 1) When no input, return "null"; 2) When input TRUE, return "true"; 3) When input FALSE, return"FALSE".

However, when I try this function, I found that input FALSE still give me "TRUE".
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j35P.png)

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Try printing `group_center` to view what value is being passed

Comment: First you are printing and Not returning. Consider returning. Second you have to cast to the underlying type. In your case, you have to cast to type boolean `LogicalVector group_center(group_center);` before you run the nested `if -else`

Comment: For starters, remove `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` and `using namespace arma;`.  This about _just_ `Rcpp` so keep it at that.  Second, did you look at the [example for `Nullable<>`](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/optional-null-function-arguments/) at the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/) ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, I checked this link before I post this. It didn't work because I used "if(val){}" instead of "if(val[0]){}" (answer below). And now it works.

Comment: Yes, `Nullable<>()` is quirky because you need to instantiate the object in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nullable object does not itself evaluate to false even if it contains a false value. You need to cast it to a logical vector and test its first element:

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void check(Nullable<LogicalVector> group_center = R_NilValue) {
  if (group_center.isNotNull()) {
    LogicalVector val(group_center);
    if (val[0]) {
      Rprintf("true.\n");
    } else {
      Rprintf("false.\n");
    }
  } else{Rprintf("null.\n");}
}
```

Now, after compilation, in R we have:

```r
check()
#> null.
check(TRUE)
#> true.
check(FALSE)
#> false.
```

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for the question! I have one more question based on this one. What if I want to set the default group_center to TRUE? Like If I don't set group_center = TRUE for the function but still get group_center = TRUE.

Comment: Sorry @spencer886 I don't really understand what you mean here. Could you try to explain again?

Comment: Never mind, I think I know how to do that now. Thank you!